# Disable a step on a flowchart

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, flowchart

I would like to disable some steps on a WF4 flowchart, before execute it.
My flowchart is very simple, a start node and 3 sequences with a WriteLine activity on each one : "Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 3".

I would like to suppress the "Step 2" sequence, so the Console must write "Step 1" \n "Step 3", here is my code (It works pefectly with a sequential workflow, but not with a flowchart !!)

```
Activity a = new Activity1();
Activity customActivity = Customize(a);
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(customActivity);
Console.ReadLine();

static System.Activities.Activity Customize(System.Activities.Activity scheme)
{
    var activities = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(scheme);
    var rootActivity = activities.FirstOrDefault();

    if (rootActivity is Sequence)
    {
        var seqActivities = ((Sequence)rootActivity).Activities;
        var badActivity = seqActivities.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DisplayName == "Step2");
        seqActivities.Remove(badActivity);
    }

    if (rootActivity is Flowchart)
    {
        var seqActivities = ((Flowchart)rootActivity).Nodes.Cast<FlowStep>().ToList();
        var badActivity = seqActivities.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Action.DisplayName == "Step2");
        bool b = ((Flowchart)rootActivity).Nodes.Remove(badActivity);
    }

    return scheme;
}
```

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. If you dynamically load the XAML using the [ActivityXamlServices.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.xamlintegration.activityxamlservices.load.aspx) you can update the XAML before you actually load and execute it. In the end XAML is just XML.
2. You can wrap the activities inside of [FlowDecision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.flowdecision.aspx) activities and only execute when you want to.